# SetCurrentConsoleFontEx doesn't set the font from GetCurrentConsoleFontEx

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-console

I call `GetCurrentConsoleFontEx` and then call `SetCurrentConsoleFontEx` with the same information. I would have expected that setting the `new_font = old_font` would have no effect.

Clearly, I was naive.

[image]
[image]

The exact program is:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0502
#include <Windows.h>
int main()
{
    HANDLE out = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX cfi1, cfi2;
    cfi1.cbSize = sizeof(cfi1);
    cfi2.cbSize = sizeof(cfi2);
    if (0 == GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(out, false, &cfi1))
        return -1;
    if (0 == SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(out, false, &cfi1))
        return -1;
    if (0 == GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(out, false, &cfi2))
        return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

The program exits with code `0`, so the API calls didn't fail.

From `cfi1` to `cfi2`, the value of `nFont`, an index into a table of fonts, changed from `1` to `3`. The size of the font's width and height, `dwFontSize`, changed from `{12, 25}` to `{15, 31}`.

Why is this happening?

EDIT: Calling `GetConsoleFontSize` when the second parameter for the calls is `false` returns the same font size as `GetCurrentConsoleFontEx`. When the second parameter is `true`, `GetConsoleFontSize` returns `{12, 15}` before and `{23, 49}` after. `GetCurrentConsoleFontEx` reports the font size to be `{80, 20}` both times. `nFont` still changes.

Comment: You should probably be checking for failure just to make sure nothing weird's going on.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Oh yeah, I should add that. The original problem ran with the checks in place, and I removed them when shortening it down.

Comment: You should read the docs for GetCurrentConsoleFontEx more carefully. It implies that the font for `true` and `false` for the second parameter may be different. Furthermore, the description of `CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX` says that you must call another function, `GetConsoleFontSize`, to get the font size.

Comment: @Puppy I wouldn't expect it to change if I use the same true/false parameter for both calls. Also, changing it to `true` instead makes the font catastrophically larger. I just verified by using `GetConsoleFontSize` before and after, and the size returned by that matches the one returned by `GetCurrentConsoleFontEx`.